# Class of referenced Library cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I know this question has been asked so many times, but I think I followed all the steps (add class folder to build path), yet Eclipse keeps complaining.

[image: Screenshot].

I am really out of ideas. I guess it might be necessary to add an import statement, but I have no clue what it should be. Whatever I tried 
e.g. import /picture.zip_expanded with or without dash, with or without * or .Circle in the end
would not be accepted.
Thanks a lot!
Thomas

Comment: "import Circle;" would be my guess, since it's in the default package.

Comment: Your Circle class is in the default package - you can't import that in to a named package.

Comment: Put the cursor on the line with error and press CTRL + 1. It will offer you the possible candidate, but Circle class from default package is not visible..

Comment: Ok, neither import Circle nor CTRL + 1 worked (I also had tried these before). Since I was given the source code of the Circle class, I took @greg-449 's comment literally and just created it afresh within my package blatt07. That works now. I do not know whether that is the way to go, though. I had imported that class from an archive the way it was told in the tutorial (File - Import - General - Projects from Folder or Archive - Archive) before. Obviously that was nonsense